# Next.js Fetched Data is not displaying in DOM

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, next.js

I have written a fetch command, I received the console.log of that data but it will not display in the DOM.

```
export default async function links(){
    const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/');
    const data = await res.json();

    // console.log(data);
    return<>
    <h1>{data.gender}</h1>
    </>
}
```

I have done:

```
export default async function links(){
    const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/');
    const data = await res.json();

    // console.log(data);
    return<>
    <h1>{data.gender}</h1>
    </>
}
```

And

```
type Repos = {
    gender: string;
    email: string;
    phone: number;
}

export default async function links(){
    const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/');
    const data = await res.json();

    // console.log(data);
    return<>
    <h1>{data.gender}</h1>
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- your component is `async`. `async components` work only netxjs13 app directory server components
- component name should be capital

  ```
   export default async function Links(){}
  ```
- `return` should be `jsx` you should wrap with `()`

  ```
  return (<>
       <h1>{data.gender}</h1>
     </>)
  ```

Comment: All good points, I have tried that and still does not seem to display the data.